# recursive function to transform multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have an array after an SQL query made with cake PHP which returns me a tree. I do not the number of  dimension of my array.

I want transform it to use it with jstree. I'm fighting with a recursive function and I didn't success.

Can you help me.

My original array looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Confsave] => Array
            (
                [id] => 815
                [Name] => 1
                [parent_id] =>
                [lft] => 1
                [rght] => 30
            )

        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [Confsave] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 816
                                [Name] => 2
                                [parent_id] => 815
                                [lft] => 2
                                [rght] => 15
                            )

                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Confsave] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 817
                                                [parent_id] => 816
                                                [lft] => 3
                                                [rght] => 8
                                            )

                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [Confsave] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [id] => 818
                                                                [Name] => 4
                                                                [parent_id] => 817
                                                                [lft] => 4
                                                                [rght] => 5
                                                            )

                                                        [children] => Array
                                                            (
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [1] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [Confsave] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [id] => 819
                                                                [Name] => 5
                                                                [parent_id] => 817
                                                                [lft] => 6
                                                                [rght] => 7
                                                            )

                                                        [children] => Array
                                                            (
                                                            )
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

And I want have something like this :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [text] => 1
        [id] => 815
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [text] => 2
                        [id] => 816
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [text] => 3
                                        [id] => 817
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [text] => 4
                                                        [id] => 818
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    )
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [text] => 5
                                        [id] => 819
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

I have try with a recursive function like this but I don't success

```
private function buildTree(array $elements) {

    $branch=array();
    foreach ($elements as $element){

        $branch[]=$element['Confsave']['Name'];
        if(is_array($element['children'])){
            $this->buildTree($element);
        }

    }
    return $branch;

}
```

Edit :
After test and remarks my function is now

```
private function buildTree(array $elements) {

    $branch=array();
    foreach ($elements as $element){

        $branch[]=$element['Confsave']['Name'];
        if(is_array($element['children'])){ 
            $this->buildTree($element['children']);
        }

    }
    return $branch;
}
```

When I am debuging, I can see that I go to my function for each child (what I want). But I don't know how to make the new array()

Comment: i didn't look at it too long but you're not assigning `$branch[$curr_index]['children']` to the return value of `$this->buildTree` inside the if statement.

Comment: does it ever have two children?

Comment: Yes I can have more than 2 children

Comment: can you show an example of an array with more than one child?

Comment: Your input doesn't match your output -- please ensure that the output array is a transformed version of the input array, not just a data structure you've made up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me...

```
$array = buildTree($array); 

print_r($array); 

function buildTree(array $parent) { 
   $branch = array();  
   foreach ($parent as $index => $element){  
      $node = array();   
      $node['id']   = $element['Confsave']['id'];
      $node['text'] = isset($element['Confsave']['Name']) ?
                            $element['Confsave']['Name']  : 'no name';
      $node['children'] = buildTree($element['children']); 
      $branch[] = $node; 
   }
   return $branch; 
}
```

---

my initial test array....

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Confsave] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 999
                    [Name] => 999
                    [parent_id] => 
                    [lft] => 1
                    [rght] => 30
                )

            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Confsave] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 777
                                    [Name] => 777
                                    [parent_id] => 999
                                    [lft] => 1
                                    [rght] => 30
                                )

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Confsave] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 888
                                    [Name] => 888
                                    [parent_id] => 999
                                    [lft] => 1
                                    [rght] => 30
                                )

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Confsave] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 815
                    [Name] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 
                    [lft] => 1
                    [rght] => 30
                )

            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Confsave] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 816
                                    [Name] => 2
                                    [parent_id] => 815
                                    [lft] => 2
                                    [rght] => 15
                                )

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Confsave] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 817
                                                    [parent_id] => 816
                                                    [lft] => 3
                                                    [rght] => 8
                                                )

                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [Confsave] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [id] => 818
                                                                    [Name] => 4
                                                                    [parent_id] => 817
                                                                    [lft] => 4
                                                                    [rght] => 5
                                                                )

                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [Confsave] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [id] => 819
                                                                    [Name] => 5
                                                                    [parent_id] => 817
                                                                    [lft] => 6
                                                                    [rght] => 7
                                                                )

                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

---

my result array....

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 999
            [text] => 999
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 777
                            [text] => 777
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 888
                            [text] => 888
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 815
            [text] => 1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 816
                            [text] => 2
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 817
                                            [text] => no name
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 818
                                                            [text] => 4
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 819
                                                            [text] => 5
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```